# Forwarding all pages to a new site

Tags: .htaccess, forwarding

I have a client with three domains:

```
mysite.com,
mysite.ie,
mysite.co.uk
```

I've set the .ie and .co.uk sites to forward to the .com with standard forwarding, which works fine.

But if someone hits a page on these sites, e.g `mysite.ie/test.html` , the site don't forward to the com, it just gives a not found error.

Is there anything I can do to get these pages to forward onto the .com site?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default 404 page to include Javascript that redirects back to the main site. Changing the 404 will depend on how your site is hosted. The Javascript could look like the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.example.com/"
</script>
```